# Obtain x86 instruction size for C++ code?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, compilation, x86

In the Visual Studio disassembly view it shows the instruction bytes for the x86 assembly, for C++ code:

```
0F B6 54 24 25       movzx       edx,byte ptr [t]
^^ these are what I want
```

I would like to be able to obtain the total instruction size for each instruction, without the C++ code having to be part of a Visual Studio project. **Ideally I would like to be able to "interpret" this information from a C# application.**

What is the best way to do this? Does GCC have an option to generate these instruction bytes as part of the assembly listing? I have only ever seen them in the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: `objdump -d` possibly `objdump -dS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. This isn't a function of gcc as much as it is an artifact of disassembling compiled code, however.  Using GCC you can compile directly to assembly, but it will not show you the hex bytes. To see the bytes, try this:

```
gcc -c my_file.s
```

This will produce `my_file.o`. With that in hand, now try this:

```
objdump -d my_file.o
```

This will disassemble the file (on the right) and show you the matching machine language (to the left).

***Update after question change***

And, yes, you can install Cygwin on Windows and objdump under Cygwin. This will allow you to easily dump your C# code in the same way.

Comment: Hi, I literally just discovered this and had to quickly edit my question. Would it be possible for me to compile the C++ code using GCC and then objdump it, all from a C# application on Windows?

Comment: Well, you could use `g++` to compile C++ code, of course, but not C# code.

Comment: No fair changing the question after it has an answer. ;)

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer because it does answer my initial question. My second question is more a C#/Windows/Cygwin question.

Comment: You can do it with cygwin under windows too. Added.

Comment: @user997112: `-Mintel` will tell objdump to disassemble in Intel syntax, not AT&T.  [Agner Fog's objconv](http://agner.org/optimize/) will disassemble into your choice of valid NASM, MASM, or AT&T syntax, with hexdump and other info in comments